# Polygon border with hachure in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

On aviation maps (ICAO map 1:500.000) restricted areas are indicated by a line with hachure pointing to the inside of the polygon.

[image: Example]

Refer to ICAO Annex 4 Appendix 2 page APP 2-9:

https://www.casa.gov.au/sites/g/files/net351/f/_assets/main/lib91135/an04_cons.pdf

Is it possible to create a line or fill style with QGIS which represents this hachure?